# Trying to call a function from another file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, function

I have a function in a class file called auth_user and its in App_code folder.
I am trying to call that function from random pages that are on the website. 
Inside the class file is a function that is simple, basicly check for flags in the sessions, i just wanna have it there so i dont have to type it again and again. 
I want to be able to call it with one function like auth_user();

How would i do this excetly ?
would the function be public static void or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static makes sense for this:

```
public class AuthUtility
{
    public static bool IsUserAuthorized()
    {
      ....
      return retVal;
    }
{
```

And then you would call it:

```
AuthUtility.IsUserAuthorized();
```

### Edit Based on Comments

So, not to be rude, but that information in your comments would've been pertinent in your original question and saved a fair amount of time.

Regardless, you'll need to pass in either the current HTTPContext or the Current Session into your static method:

```
public class AuthUtility
{
    public static void AuthorizeUser(HttpSessionState currentSession)
    {
        currentSession["whatev"] = "rockin";
        .....
    }
}
```

And the you would call it:

```
AuthUtility.AuthorizeUser(this.Session);
```

Comment: cant get it to work.. i get confused with the static, void and allt that.. dont get the whole diffrence..

if the function is not returning any value.. i would use void right ?
the function is just doing some stuff.. but not returning some value..

Comment: If you're not returning a value, then void would be correct.  Static means that you don't need to create a new instance of the class to call the method.  What error are you getting?

Comment: This works if i use public void a_user().. then i have to make a new instance of it then run it, dont want that.

if i put static in it i get some errors like this.

"Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Session.get'"

I am using sessions and server.transfers in the function